# Disable outbound DHCP option code 252 in Windows

Tags: windows, firewall, windows-firewall

Reading https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.hu/2017/12/apacolypse-now-exploiting-windows-10-in_18.html it seems like it's a *very* good idea to disable this. Quite obviously, though, I can't find anything pertaining to disabling any such kind of traffic. Can the built in firewall do this? If not, what other product can?

Edit: I missed from the article (because it ends with listing the things that don't work and mention the only thing that does before) is you can disable WPAC itself by running this from an elevated Command Prompt: `REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinHttpAutoProxySvc /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f`. The question still stands even if it is much less pressing now.

Answer (score -1):

DHCP typically happens with either 0.0.0.0 or 255.255.255.255 as IP addresses as the DHCP server is responsible for handing out IP addresses on port 67 or 68.

**You can not just block these ports as DHCP will no longer function at all.**

This option requires that you are operating a DHCP server such as bind or whatever windows calls their server.

**Most DHCP servers have no options enabled by default.**

Unless you are in a business, and then the IT department secures the DHCP against these kinds of attacks.

Some managed routers have more options, but only a handful of home users buy those as they are **significantly** more expensive.

Home routers and most devices provided by ISP are too dumb to support any such options.  Unless you modded your routers firmware with OpenWrt, dd wrt, or similar.  Goto your routers config page, and you will see start, end range and subnet and those are all the options you will likely have.

Complex configurations are only possible with real DHCP servers.  To use the simplest DHCP server options I had to disable the built-in server and run a Linux server to get a DHCP server I could meaningfully configure my self.

You will need a product with deep packet inspection, like wireshark, which can decode the dhcp server request.  Now decoding it isn't enough you also need to remove or replace the option 252.

Comment: Not sure why are we talking about routers and servers when at least the title but also the linked article makes it crystal clear the question is about *Windows*.

Comment: @chx because The DHCP server that Windows uses is provided by your router or a server.  If you don't have a DHCP server you have to use static IP addresses in which case windows will not accept option code 252 nor any other code.

Comment: But the adversial case is when I don't control the server and need to stop Windows from reaching out.

Comment: @chx  Then you have to disable DHCP and give every PC and device a manual static IP.  Then a rogue DHCP server will be ignored.